# Proving $A-B⊆ A$ with set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove this claim but I am not sure about the step $$x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B = A$$  and the step $$A → A = A$$ in my proof. Could someone verify my proof?

> Let $x ∈ A-B$.\begin{align*}
> &\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} A-B⊆ A\\
> &= ∀x \{x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B → x ∈ A \} &&\text{[Definition of subset]}\\
> &= ∀x \{x ∈ A → x ∈ A \}          &&[A ∧ x ∉ B = A]\\
> &= ∀x \{x ∈(A → A ) \}             &&\text{[Distributivity]}\\
> &= ∀x \{x ∈ A \}                   &&[A → A = A]\\
> &= A.
> \end{align*}

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Write math in sentences that make sense when  read word-for-word in ordinary speech.  "x belongs to A and x does not belong to B equals A" is unintelligible. So is "A implies A equals A". Try writing things in words first and do NOT try to be brief, and then convert them to mathematical short forms.... and don't use $=$ for $\iff$ (coded here as \iff).

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand this notation.. Never seen it before. It makes no sense: an inclusion statement is not a set.

But $A - B \subseteq A$ is trivial the standard way: let $x \in A- B$. Then
$x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, so in particular $x \in A$ (we can use one half of an "and"-clause). So $A -B \subseteq A$ has been shown.

Comment: I'm Just wana say ∀x{A−B→x∈A} this is by the def. of subset is there is wrong with it ?

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi Your notation makes no sense.

Comment: OK , but i need one more clarification                                                                           in case (A∩B ∩C)⊆ (A∩B). if I assume  x∈ A∩B∩C that mean x∈A ∧x ∈B∧x∈C ,                                                                                 my goal is the ask you could we use a part of our assumption and Regardless of the rest (In this case will be x∈C) And make assumption serve us to proof claims?

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi yes that proof goes the same way, using only part of the and clause